# How to detect when Facebook plugin has finished loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

I created a modal to display a Facebook page plugin, the modal works fine but displays a white window for a few seconds until Facebook plugin is loaded.

Is there a way to detect when Facebook plugin has finished loading to display modal ?

```
<!-- FB CODE -->
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/fr_FR/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.4&appId=1380256915546834";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
<!-- FB CODE END -->

<div id="form_fields_container"> 
<div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/myfanpage" data-small-header="false" data-adapt-container-width="true" data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="false" data-show-posts="false"></div>
```

```
<script>
    var dom = {};
    dom.query = jQuery.noConflict( true );
      function openColorBox(){
        dom.query.colorbox({
            iframe:false, 
            width:"400", 
            height:"250", 
            inline: true,
            href: "#form_fields_container",
            onLoad: function() {
                dom.query('#form_fields_container').show();
              },
            onClosed: function() {
                dom.query('#form_fields_container').fadeOut();
              },
            });
      }

      dom.query("#form_fields_container").ready(function(){  
        openColorBox();
      });

    </script>
```

Comment: There is the [`xfbml.render` event](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/v2.4); but I think that is fired when the SDK is finished creating the iframes, and doesn’t actually report when the resources in those iframes have finished loading.